# .NET Garbage Collector difference between x86 / x64. x64 doesn't collect

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have a WPF application which doesn't seem to garbage collect on x64 systems. I have tested it carefully on x86 machines and I am confident it isn't a programming problem, the memory usage will grow and then will be garbage collected as I expect.  The target platform = 'Any CPU'

I have discovered that I can eliminate this behaviour on x64 machines by compiling with the target = x86.  x64 or 'Any CPU' fails to release memory.

I also noticed during my investigations that creating a child application domain and manually minimizing the application working set works on x86 but is ignored on x64 systems.  Until I set the target = x86.

Does anyone know why this behaviour exists?  Do we need to avoid 'Any CPU' or x64?

Comment: What amount of free memory was at that machine? And what is the total amount of memory there?

Comment: At least some editions of Windows 32-bit will force a minimize of an application's working set when you minimize it. Perhaps that was eliminated from the 64-bit versions.

Comment: Don't use Taskmgr.exe to diagnose GC issues.

Answer (score 2):

The Garbage Collector runs when it decides it needs to run. This is typically a matter of the amount of memory usage as well as the amount of free memory.

If the machine(s) in question has a lot of memory, there's no reason for the GC to execute.  In x86 machines, memory pressure is usually an issue, since the total allowable memory for a process is much smaller (normally 2gb), and the total for the system is low overall (~3gb).  64bit systems don't have those limitations, so the GC will likely run less often.

Remember, though, this isn't a bad thing - using memory is **good**, provided you don't run out.  More GC collections just reduces your overall performance, and only is a good thing if your running low on available memory.  Otherwise, you might as well use the memory that's available.